# Unload a plugin with pluginlib

Tags: ros, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

i'm trying to manage a project with the adaptation of plugins and I created a node with the launch of multiple plugins with different parameters and I can't found in the API code a function to unload a plugin dynamically. I'd like not to use any nodelet because there are some specifications that I don't understand (The bond connection between every nodelets and all).

So is there a simple way to manage the plugin dynamically ?

Thx

Edit 1:

I tried to use the unloadLibraryForClass. It does not delete the object, it just tries to unload the library which is not what I want.

What I'm trying to do for example is to instantiate a plugin, delete it and instantiate it again with a different parameter. The destructor of the base class is virtual so I create a destructor for each of my plugin but it cannot be used because the plugin is of the base type. Same problem with the delete function.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269314/unload-a-plugin-with-pluginlib/) by [bulgrozer](https://answers.ros.org/users/22356/bulgrozer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2017-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The C++ API docs list a [int pluginlib::ClassLoader<T>::unloadLibraryForClass(const std::string &lookup_name)](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/pluginlib/html/classpluginlib_1_1ClassLoader.html#ab1329aca6481d04c74422f0761603620) method:

> Decrements the counter for the library containing a class with a given name and attempts to unload it if the counter reaches zero.

That should do what you want, but *only* in the case that no other users of the library still hold on to it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0